# Django get request via ajax making two requests

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views

I am working on passing data from ajax to a Django view. However, ajax somehow is making 2 GET requests: one with the query string and the other without it. In the view when I try to get the query string its empty.

Ajax code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var query = "{{ item.ipv4_address }}";
    $("#clickid").click(function() {
            $.ajax({

                    url: "/reserve/run/?ip=",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {ip:query},
                    success:function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                    }
            });
   });
});


</script>
```

Django view:

```
def run_script(request):

    if request.GET:
        ip = request.GET['ip']
        print ip 

    return render_to_response('test.html',{'item':ip})
```

Two urls:

```
[16/Dec/2017 07:43:56] "GET /reserve/run/?ip=198.18.101.123 HTTP/1.1" 200 570
[16/Dec/2017 07:03:58] "GET /reserve/run/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1
```

urls.py file

```
url(r'^run/$',views.run_script,name='run_script'),
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Also, let me know if you need any more info. Any pointers is appreciated.

Comment: Did you print it in the `view` and checked if it's really making 2 requests ??

Comment: No I am not printing anything except for the IP I am trying to pass as a query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. In my  tag, I had mentioned the URL too. {% url 'run_script' %}. This was sending that extra GET request. Once I removed it, the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing query parameter in your data attribute you need not to send it in url parameter.Update your url parameter as:

```
$.ajax({

                url: "/reserve/run/",
                type: "GET",
                data: {ip:query},
                success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                }
        });
```

Comment: The url requests has reversed now:
`[16/Dec/2017 07:43:46] "GET /reserve/run/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1`

`[16/Dec/2017 07:43:56] "GET /reserve/run/?ip=198.18.101.123 HTTP/1.1" 200 570`

Comment: I have included urls.py I believe some issue lies in here.

Comment: Are you getting the value of `"{{ item.ipv4_address }}"` in your html?

Comment: Actually it is part of a modal. The modal takes 2 seconds to load. After it loads the `"{{ item.ipv4_address }}"` becomes available. I am able to see it console logs.

Comment: Please check that your element with id 'clickid' is clicked only once.It may be possible that as your modal takes time to load till then the element gets clicked.